# In detectron2, how could I put the keypoint names on the image?

Tags: python, computer-vision, object-detection, detectron, keypoint

First, I will explain the problem statement. I am wuing Detectron2 for keypoint detection for my custom dataset. I am using the below code to visualize the bounding box and the keyoints.

```
outputs = predictor(im[..., ::-1])
v = Visualizer(im[:, :, ::-1], MetadataCatalog.get(cfg.DATASETS.TRAIN[0]), scale=1.2)
out = v.draw_instance_predictions(outputs["instances"].to("cpu"))
plt.figure(figsize=(60,30))
plt.imshow(out.get_image()[..., ::-1][..., ::-1])
```

I get the output as an image below.

[image]

As you can see, the class label and the two keypoints are drawn on the image by the detectron2 visualizer. The two keypoint names are [keypoint_up, keypoint_down].

I want to print the names of the two keypoint on the image as well. Someting like below example.

[image]

I know detectron provide a function called [draw_text](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/modules/utils.html?highlight=draw_text#detectron2.utils.visualizer.Visualizer.draw_text). If anyone has an idea of how I could use it to put the keypoint name on the image, that would be a great help. A coding example would be very useful. Any other solution except the draw_text function is also welcomed. Thank you for your time